# Change Selection in Multi-Select via function in jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I am using using a jQuery plugin to achieve a Multi-Select selection [Plugin Github](https://github.com/mysociety/jquery-multi-select) [Demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multiple-Select-With-Checkboxes-multi-select-js/).
Now I would like to artificially change the selection of the drop-down menu from another function.
So what I have is this:

HTML part:

```
<select id="Fruits" name="Fruits" multiple="" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1">Number1</option>
    <option value="2">Number2</option>
    <option value="3">Number3</option>
</select>
```

Then I use that code to initialise the menu:

```
$(function(){
   $('#Fruits').multiSelect({'noneText':'Select Fruits'});
});
```

The result is:

[image: Menu Fruits]

Now I would like to select a certain option by running another function:

[image: Menu Fruits Option1 Selected]

As I am not really familiar with jQuery I have a hard time understanding the sourcecode of the Plugin. So far I have tried things like this:

```
$("#Fruits").data("plugin_multiSelect").updateButtonContents()
```

or

```
$("#Fruits").data("plugin_multiSelect").$element.on('change.multiselect')
```

It seems I am a bit lost.

Comment: `.$element.on('change.multiselect')` is the event triggered when stuff is selected

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you! That's why I tried it. It simply calls ```_this.updateButtonContents()```. I think I need to somehow get the option box that I want to select into the "_this"?

Comment: I just see that ```updateButtonContents()``` is looking for "selected" ```if $(this).is(':selected')) {selected.push( $.trim(text) );}``` How can I mark an entry as selected?

Comment: I would choose a different plugin or ask the author https://github.com/mysociety/jquery-multi-select/issues - there is not even an example in the demo code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the syntax to change the selection state of the multi-select. It would be:

```
$('#Fruits').val(["0","4"]);
$("#Fruits").data("plugin_multiSelect").updateMenuItems();
```

So that would get the 1st and 5th element of the drop-down "Fruits" selected.